# How can I combine nine holiday light cords into one?

Tags: electrical

I have a Christmas village that had 9 different electrical cords to each building, is there a way to join each cord together to make one continual cord with nine lights

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Welcome. What I posted there is the boilerplate response for questions without enough information. Please revise to describe layout, cord type, current requirements, etc. Photos would be fantastic. If you're asking about modifying the cords, be aware that you'll void UL listing and possibly violate electrical code. This is partly why such details are critical.

Comment: Are you familiar with power strips and 3-to-1 splitters?  Our first question will surely be "Why aren't those good enough?"  Generally on StackExchange we want to know what you've done so far to work the problem.

Comment: Even though 3-1 splitters are legal I would lean to power strips as I have seen more problems from 3 in 1 , also most strips have switches and some have built in over current protection.

Answer (score 2):

My wife has a large holiday village also, these are fairly low wattage so combining them on a power strip is ok. 
The advantage that she likes is everything can be turned off with 1 switch she actually has 3 power strips connected to power all the buildings and street lights, I measured the current and with everything running it was drawing almost 8 amps. This is well below what the circuit and power strips are rated for, I am glad she finally ran out of room to set up any more.